# Definite article "The" moved to the back of the "title" of an article (solved)

Tags: bibliographies, legal-style

I love LaTeX, but sadly there is not style for the *Bluebook Uniform System of Citation* used in Law Schools. I won't go back to Word Processors, so I decided to tweak some existing style into something minimally useful. I have moved close to the desired result departing from [Will Hardy's](http://willhardy.com.au/aglc-and-latex/) *Australian Guide to Legal Citation 2 or AGLC2*, but I''ve found some obstacles. One of them is the "The" of a title, moving to its back (in the MWE it is in FN number 6).

The files I use are the following:

- [Will Hardy's ALC2](http://willhardy.com.au/aglc-and-latex/) (aglc2.bbx and aglc2.cbx)
- A biblatex.cgf which looks I feel are probably irrelevant for this question.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sortlocale=auto, style=aglc2, citestyle=aglc2]{biblatex}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{america2.bib}

\begin{document}

This paper is an example of how footnotes should work in \emph{Bluebook}, the 
style of citation used in American legal academia. We call authors such as Friedman, 
who we think is awesome.\footcite[578]{friedman1} And we think he is awesome again.\footcite[578]{friedman1}

And we cite him again.\footcite[578]{friedman1} But then we move on and cite some 
other guy for ``a new jurisprudence of judicial restraint.''\footcite{balkin}

Some other guy gets cited \footcite{kurland} and then we cite Friedman again
but with another article.\footcite{friedman2} But then we cite a book.\footcite[22]{parker}

And we cite Kurland again\footcite{kurland}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Sorry about not including the america2.bib file before:

```
@article{friedman1,
    title = {Dialogue and Judicial Review},
    volume = {91},
    issn = {00262234},
    url = {},
    doi = {10.2307/1289700},
    pages = {577},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Michigan Law Review},
    author = {Friedman, Barry},
    urldate = {2014-06-03},
    date = {1993-02},
    file = {}
}

@book{parker,
    title = {Here, the People Rule: A Constitutional Populist Manifesto},
    volume = {},
    url = {},
    shorttitle = {Here, the People Rule},
    pages = {},
    journaltitle = {},
    shortjournal = {},
    author = {Parker, Richard D.},
    date = {1992},
    file = {}
}

@article{friedman2,
    title = {Importance of Being Positive: The Nature and Function of Judicial Review, The},
    volume = {72},
    url = {},
    shorttitle = {Importance of Being Positive},
    pages = {1257},
    journaltitle = {University of Cincinnati Law Review},
    shortjournal = {U. Cin. L. Rev.},
    author = {Friedman, Barry},
    date = {2003},
    file = {}
}

@article{kurland,
    title = {The Supreme Court, 1963 Term},
    volume = {78},
    issn = {{0017811X}},
    url = {},
    doi = {10.2307/1338853},
    pages = {143},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Harvard Law Review},
    author = {Kurland, Philip B.},
    urldate = {2014-06-03},
    date = {1964-11},
    file = {}
}

@article{balkin,
    title = {Understanding the Constitutional Revolution},
    volume = {87},
    url = {},
    pages = {1045},
    journaltitle = {Virginia Law Review},
    shortjournal = {Va. L. Rev.},
    author = {Balkin, Jack M. and Levinson, Sanford},
    date = {2001},
    file = {}
}
```

Comment: I hardly think this has anything to do with the `.bbx`/`.cbx` file, it is more likely thanks to the format in your `.bib` file. Would you mind sharing the `.bib` entry for `kurland`, `friedman1` and `friedman2` with us?

Comment: You are right! How silly of me not to look at the bib file first. I guess Zotero took the "The" out and has nothing to do with style files. This question has been answered. Thanks so much.

Comment: Should I delete once a question has been answered or leve it there?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to wrong data in the Bib file

Comment: I think you should edit the question to make the title more generally informative and answer the question yourself. The question isn't really about TeX but someone with a bad .bib file might find help here just knowing that was the problem. Good for you for committing to TeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been **answered**. Thanks everybody for the input. It turns out that the problem was in the .bib file and not in the style or Biblatex customization files. Zotero has apparently moved the location of the definite article "The" on the *title* of an article which name is "The importance of being positive", maybe for indexing purposes.